# If Header is itself not present and we want to validate and proceed in routeBuilder in Camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, openshift

I am facing an issue in camel coding as:

1). We have two layers of code , first one is consumer and another is producer.
2). Consumer is calling producer as producer has many microservices.
3). During call Producer is generating the Unique ID for transaction tracking.
4). We can call the producer directly and it will generate the resultset.
5). During the Producer call we have to add the Unique Log transaction ID in header from POSTMAN.

Now the question is if want to hit the producer directly and do not want to pass the log transaction ID, Is there any way that
my producer router understands that LOGTRANSACTION is not present in header and it will generate a header named as "LOGTRANSACTION"
and add the unique value ?

and if we hit the Consumer then the LOGTRANSACTION ID propagate as it is to the producer layer.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming the `header` you are talking about is a Camel message header; you may add a new `Processor` in front of your existing route to inspect the incoming `Message` with `getHeader("LOGTRANSACTION");`,. If this header is not present, your new processor can do a `setHeader("LOGTRANSACTION", newHeader);` to attach it synthetically(somehow!). Bear in mind that If you do `exchange.getIn().getHeader()` all the inbound headers and body will be preserved but calls to `getOut()` will clear original `IN` message. If you want further (better) answers, please consider posting relevant parts of your route(s) as well.